# Locating a valid NGINX template for nginx-ingress-controller? (Kubernetes)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to follow this tutorial on configuring nginx-ingress-controller for a Kubernetes cluster I deployed to AWS using kops.

https://daemonza.github.io/2017/02/13/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/

When I run **kubectl create -f ./nginx-ingress-controller.yml**, the pods are created but error out. From what I can tell, the problem lies with the following portion of nginx-ingress-controller.yml:

```html
volumes:
        - name: tls-dhparam-vol
          secret:
            secretName: tls-dhparam
        - name: nginx-template-volume
          configMap:
            name: nginx-template
            items:
            - key: nginx.tmpl
              path: nginx.tmpl
```

Error shown on the pods:

MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nginx-template-volume" : configmaps "nginx-template" not found

This makes sense, because the tutorial does not have the reader create this configmap before creating the controller. I know that I need to create the configmap using:

**kubectl create configmap nginx-template --from-file=nginx.tmpl=nginx.tmpl**

I've done this using **nginx.tmpl** files found from sources [like this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl), but they don't seem to work (always fail with invalid NGINX template errors). Log example:

```html
I1117 16:29:49.344882       1 main.go:94] Using build: https://github.com/bprashanth/contrib.git - git-92b2bac
I1117 16:29:49.402732       1 main.go:123] Validated default/default-http-backend as the default backend
I1117 16:29:49.402901       1 main.go:80] mkdir /etc/nginx-ssl: file exists already exists
I1117 16:29:49.402951       1 ssl.go:127] using file '/etc/nginx-ssl/dhparam/dhparam.pem' for parameter ssl_dhparam
F1117 16:29:49.403962       1 main.go:71] invalid NGINX template: template: nginx.tmpl:1: function "where" not defined
```

The image version used is quite old, but I've tried newer versions with no luck.

```html
 containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
```

[This thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2061) is similar to my issue, but I don't quite understand the proposed solution. Where would I use docker cp to extract a usable template from? Seems like the templates I'm using use a language/syntax incompatible with Docker...?

Answer (score 3):

To copy the nginx template file from the ingress controller pod to your local machine, you can first grab the name of the pod with `kubectl get pods` then run `kubectl exec [POD_NAME] -it -- cat /etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl > nginx.tmpl`.

This will leave you with the `nginx.tmpl` file you can then edit and push back up as a configmap. I would recommend though keeping custom changes to the template to a minimum as it can make it hard for you to update the controller in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did the trick for me... Thanks! I had to comment out all lines in nginx-ingress-controller.yml that to do with volumes/volumemounts first (this allowed containers run properly so that I could run your exec command to generate the template). Once I generated the nginx.tmpl file, I uncommented those lines and the containers came up without any errors!